# Use a style template and bibliography when knitting with knit() and pandoc()

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc

**How can I use a `*.docx` style template and a `*.bib` bibliography when knitting a `*.Rmd` file with `knit()` and `pandoc()` from the R command line?**

I have an R Markdown document that relies on a bunch of simulation results that are slow to load.  Rather than knitting the document from the RStudio menu, I load the results first, then run the *.Rmd file using `knit()` and `pandoc()`.

```
load("Sim.RData")
library(knitr)
knit("MyPub.Rmd")
pandoc("MyPub.md", format="docx")
```

This works fine until I try to incorporate a style template for Word or a bibliography with citations.  For example, here is a simple *.Rmd file.

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "Today"
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: template.docx
bibliography: bibliography.bib
---

# Header 1

## Header 2

For more information see @Youngs1980.

# References
```

If I knit this *.Rmd by knitting the document from the RStudio menu, it successfully pulls in the style information from `template.docx` and the bibliography info from `bibliography.bib`, both of which are in my project directory.

[image]

But if I use `knit()` and `pandoc()` instead of knitting from the menu, neither the style nor the bibliography is incorporated.

[image]

I don't get any warning or error messages.  My first thought was that pandoc was not finding the style and bibliography files.  So, I copied them to my default pandoc directory, `C:\Users\jvadams\AppData\Roaming\pandoc`.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: Rather than using `knit` and `pandoc` separately, you might be easier to use the [render](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmarkdown/versions/1.10/topics/render) function. I expect this will solve your problem

Comment: That worked, @MichaelHarper.  If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `knit` and `pandoc` separately, I would recommend using the `render` [function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmarkdown/versions/1.10/topics/render) from the **rmarkdown** package. This function essentially combines the two functions into one and makes it easier to control the pandoc settings according the YAML specified.

This still has the benefit of loading the dataset prior to knitting the report. Using your example it would look like this:

```
load("Sim.RData")
library(rmarkdown)
render("MyPub.Rmd")
```